# Android and bluetooth headset volume

Tags: android, bluetooth

My problem is - how to set up bluetooth incall audio volume.

Since there some apps for this, no one of them works.

Anyway - no app - create one for yourself. I'm very begginer in android development, so i've tried use audioManager.setStreamVolume(), but without any luck - only internal audio has changed after this.

Even playing with startBluetoothSCO() wasn't the answer.

After looking in logcat, how os responds to pressing volume keys, i found out, that after startBluetoothSCO() volume keys in my phone sends AT commands instead of mangling streams (AT+VGM=0...15).

So my code should look something like this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
// send AT commands
audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

Crawling thru web provide me answer that there's no way to directly access modem (and propably other comm ports) from Android API.

So, maybe someone has any goddamn idea how to prevent resetting BT volume on each connect/disconnect to headset? Using code that i could use by myself, or using some 3-rd party app that is available somewhere.

OS: GB 2.3.4, SGS

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can send AT commands via [RFCOMM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) connection. But you must do this before the Android has created Headset/Handsfree Profile connection (Called Phone audio in bluetooth settings menu), or at least disconnect the HSP/HFP then connect via RFCOMM on either of the two (Both HSP and HFP should work with unsolicited +VGS commands), set the volume, and then reconnect.